# Passing JSON (dict) vs. Model Object to Templates in Django

Tags: python, django

## Question

In Django, when using data from an API (that doesn't need to be saved to the database) in a view, is there reason to prefer one of the following:

1. Convert API data (json) to a json dictionary and pass to the template
2. Convert API data (json) to the appropriate model object from models.py and then pass that to the template

#### What I've Considered So Far

- Performance: I timed both approaches and averaged them over 25 iterations. Converting the API response to a model object was slower by approximately 50ms (0.4117 vs. 0.4583 seconds, +11%). This did not include timing rendering.
- Not saving this data to the database does prevent me from creating many-to-many relationships with the API's data (must save an object before adding M2M relationships), however, I want the API to act as the store for this data, not my app
- DRY: If I find myself using this API data in multiple views, I may find convenience in putting all my consumption/cleaning/etc. code in the appropriate object `__init__` in models.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Will the templates be used with anything other than the API?

Comment: Yes. I will have to use one other model from the `models.py` in addition to data from the API on certain templates.

Comment: When do you need to save the data? At the time of pulling it or later on?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I do not have to store the data. Ideally, I can use the API as the data source for each request and avoid storing the database at all. Thanks.

Comment: Then pull the data, put it in some cache and use the cache instead.

Comment: Good point. I'll be using your suggestion about cacheing responses in conjunction with @jasisz's approach below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting this to a model objects doesn't require storing it in database.

Also if you are sure you don't want to store it maybe placing it in models.py and making it Django models is wrong idea. Probably it should be just normal Python classes e.g. in resources.py or something like that, not to mistake it with models. I prefer such way because maybe converting is slower (very tiny) but it allows to add not only custom constructor but others methods and properties as well which is very helpful. It also is just convenient and organizes stuff when you use normal classes and objects.

Comment: I elected to go this route. I've defined my data model in resources.py and I'll use it to apply some handy features like methods, cacheing etc. (as you pointed out). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the list of dictionaries directly to the template. When you need to use it with models, use [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) to get a list of dictionaries from it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've elected to go with @jasisz's as it allows me to use some handy features (custom methods, etc.). Cheers!